# Template member function unable to infer type automatically

Tags: c++, function, class, templates, overloading

What I want to do is have a function return different types depending on the input. (essentially an “overload” for return types)

I templated the function, but it isn’t able to deduce types automatically and I have to manually put the type needed.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct S {

    template<typename T>
    T Get(int type) {
        if (type == 0) {
            return 4;
        } else if (type == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    };

};

int main() {
    cout << boolalpha;

    S s;
    
    // ok
    int x = s.Get<int>(0); // return an integer
    bool y = s.Get<bool>(1); // return a boolean
    
    // ERROR
    // the end goal is something like this
    // is there a better way to handle this?
    int a = s.Get(0);
    bool b = s.Get(1);

    cout << "x: " << x << '\n'; // “x: 4”
    cout << "y: " << y << '\n'; // “y: true”

}
```

Comment: I’m using C++ 17.

Comment: There is no such thing in C++ as overloading on return type.   It is possible to return a variant, which is essentially a typesafe union that can contain one type at a time.

Comment: @Peter I’m already close enough to a favourable result, the problem is that when calling I can’t just use Get();, I have to use Get<dataType>() in order for it to work. I want to know if I can get the template to deduce the type automatically.

Comment: @xKaihatsu   - What information do you consider is in the call `some_S.Get(some_integral_value)`  for the compiler to deduce the return type of the `Get()` member function, particularly if (at the call point) the `Get()` member function has been declared but not defined.

Answer (score 2):

For your end goal, perhaps what you need is some template specialization. Something like this could work:

```
template<unsigned S>
struct getHelp; // A helper to help us switch on the number, to get the type.

template<>
struct getHelp<0> { // If our number is 0, we have int type with value 4.
    constexpr static int value = 4;
};

template<>
struct getHelp<1> { // If our number is 1, we have bool type value true.
    constexpr static bool value = true;
};

template<unsigned S>  // We have our function, it overloads the return type based
                      // on that that of the return type of our helper.
constexpr auto get() -> decltype(getHelp<S>::value) {
    return getHelp<S>::value;
}
```

Usage would be:

```
auto a = get<1>();
```

*Note: If your intention is for the number dictating your type to be dynamic (ie. passed in by a user), then what you are trying to do is impossible. c++ is a statically typed language, the best you can do is to use a `std::variant` with all possible types.*

[Here is a live example](https://ideone.com/8WCqGB)

Answer (score 2):

If you have C++17 then you can use `if-constexpr` like this:

```
struct S {

    template<int type>
    auto Get() {
        if constexpr (type == 0) {
            return 4;
        }
        else if constexpr (type == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    };

};
```

Now depending on the value of `type` the correct `if-constexpr` branch will get compiled and return the appropriate type.

You would use the above code like this:

```
S s;

int x = s.Get<0>(); // return an integer
bool y = s.Get<1>(); // return a boolean
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xrjEsG).

Note that the `type` value has to be known at compile time. In C++ you can't have a function that returns different types given a value at runtime. You would have to use `std::variant` or `std::any` to do that.

Comment: This is a super neat c++17 answer. Well done with `constexpr if`, sometimes I forget this exists. This is the best answer here.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not possible, since the type has to be known at compile time, and C++ doesn’t support constexpr function arguments. That is:

```
// valid
template <int key> 
auto fun() { if constexpr (key==0) return true; }

// unsupported
auto fun(constexpr int key)
{ if constexpr (key == 0) return true; }
```